# Cuál sería el comando SQL Server para copiar filas de una tabla que esta en una base de datos o otra tabla de otra base de datos

Tags: sql-server

Suponiendo que tengo:

Base1
Tabla1

Base2
Tabla2

Tabla1 contiene filas.
Tabla2 está vacía.

Lo que deseo es el comando para transferir las filas de Base1 - Tabla1 a la tabla Tabla2 de Base2. Ambas bases de datos tienen estructuras idénticas.

Me parece que es con INSERT INTO, pero no me sale.

**¿Cuál sería el comando para copiarlo en Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes utiliza el Insert into en la Base de datos y tablas que quieres hacer la copiar "Base2" y haces el select de la Base de datos y tablas que tiene los datos que segun tu ejemplo es "Base1".

Aqui el codigo

```sql
INSERT INTO Base2.Tabla2 (columna1, columna2, columna3)
SELECT columna1, columna2, columna3, ...
FROM Base1.Tabla1;
```

Comment: Gracias de nuevo.